# PyQt, Toggle between different View-Layouts?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

so I am using PyQt and the Qt Designer to create a little tool that is loading up data from a file.

I would like to have three buttons above a table (does not have to be a QTableWidget if there is a better solution), the table is displaying things like a small image, name, and other related stuff.

I would like to toggle between the design of the table, like button 1 displays only a list, button 2 the same list but with images in column0 and button3 should show huge images instead of tiny list entries, is there a Widget to use or how should I try to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: You could show me what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, I will try again to describe, you know in windows explorer, you have the button where you can change the view of the files in a folder like "details", or "big images" or "list". I want to provide a Table in my window, displaying the loaded data based on which View is selected.